# R separate and merge within for loop - is there a quicker/easier/better way?

Tags: r, tidyr

I receive data with fields which need to be split/separated such as the simplified fiction below (only 2 such fields are listed but there could be 2, 10, or none and not all fields will have to be separated):

```
df <- data.frame(    MgrID =  c("111A", "111B", "111C"),
                     Empl = c("ATL\\Sam", "ATL\\Sarah", "MNL\\Ethel"),
                     Desk = c("ATL\\D123", "HOM\\H1", "MNL\\M456")
                )
```

To split them out, I have a list holding the field which needs to be split and the new names which should be used after the separation (see example below):

```
# ID which fields need to be separated within df above and what the new fields should be
    L1 <- c(Empl), c("City", "Name"))
    L2 <- c(Desk), c("Site", "Location"))
    ToSep <- list(L1, L2)
```

The "ToSep" list created above would look like this when completed:

```
   ToSep
   [[1]]
   [1] "Empl" "City" "Name"

   [[2]]
   [1] "Desk"     "Site"     "Location"
```

and essentially is a pair of both what needs to be split and what the new column names should be (e.g. - split the "Empl" column into "City" and "Name" columns.

I can use the following for-loop to separate and recombine the fields back into the existing dataframe:

```
df1 <- df # Creating temp df to use inside for loop
    for (i in 1:length(ToSep)) {
      # Separate selected fields for each i  
      df2 <- df %>% 
        separate(ToSep[[i]][1], ToSep[[i]][-1], "\\\\", remove = FALSE, fill="left")
     
      # Merge current df1 with new df2 (df holding the split fields) 
      df1 <- merge(
        df1,
        df2,
        by = colnames(df),
        all = TRUE
      )
      
    }
df <- df1
```

This seems a bit clunky and I am thinking there must be a way to simplify and make more readible/faster/better/smarter/etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```r
for (el in ToSep) {
  df <- tidyr::separate(df, el[1], into = el[-1])
}
df
#   MgrID City  Name Site Location
# 1  111A  ATL   Sam  ATL     D123
# 2  111B  ATL Sarah  HOM       H1
# 3  111C  MNL Ethel  MNL     M456
```

or perhaps more simply:

```r
Reduce(function(df, el) separate(df, el[1], el[-1]),
       ToSep, init = df)
```

I notice that your code is keeping the original columns un-separated. If you still want this, try this:

```r
Reduce(function(df, el) separate(df, el[1], el[-1]),
       ToSep, init = df) %>%
  bind_cols(df[sapply(ToSep, `[[`, 1)])
#   MgrID City  Name Site Location       Empl      Desk
# 1  111A  ATL   Sam  ATL     D123   ATL\\Sam ATL\\D123
# 2  111B  ATL Sarah  HOM       H1 ATL\\Sarah   HOM\\H1
# 3  111C  MNL Ethel  MNL     M456 MNL\\Ethel MNL\\M456
```

---

Data

```r
df <- data.frame(    MgrID =  c("111A", "111B", "111C"),
                     Empl = c("ATL\\Sam", "ATL\\Sarah", "MNL\\Ethel"),
                     Desk = c("ATL\\D123", "HOM\\H1", "MNL\\M456")
                )

ToSep <- list(
  c("Empl", "City", "Name"),
  c("Desk", "Site", "Location")
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this and I can see that this is what I was looking for and that it works.  However, I am confused because the ToSep arg doesn't seem to fit when looking at the definition--> [reduce(.x, .f, ..., .init, .dir = c("forward", "backward"))] 
i.e. - it looks like...
Function(df, el) separate(df, el[1], el[-1]) ->  matches to .x and .f (the starting data to be worked and the function to use using it as a shorthand anonymous function)
init = df ->  matches to the .init argument
Where does ToSep come in?  It doesn't seem to have a place in the definition.

Comment: FYI - it looks like I can simply add back the remove = FALSE into the separate f(x) in order to keep the original cols. 
i.e. - this seems to work instead of adding the bind_cols portion:
Reduce(function(df, el) separate(df, el[1], el[-1], remove = FALSE), ToSep, init = df)

Comment: For your first comment ... you say `reduce` and I used `Reduce`. Same purpose, same effect, different function. If you want to use a different function, you need to pay attention to the arguments and change as appropriate. Second: makes sense, glad it works.

Comment: thanks, that case difference caught me.  I am still trying to wrap my head around the function process (i.e. - nailing the step-by-step that the function is actually performing) so that may take more reading.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `reduce` from `purrr` package combined with `left_join()`.

1. With `reduce()` we iteratively apply the same function to the list of columns to separate.
2. The function separates the column into the new column names using `separate()`
3. `left_join()` joins the resulting data frame with the original data frame.
4. Finally the `.init` parameter is used to initialize the reduction with the original data frame

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

reduce(
  ToSep,
  function(df, x) {
    df %>% 
      separate(x[1], into = x[-1], sep = "\\\\", remove = FALSE, fill = "left") %>% 
      left_join(df, by = names(df))
  },
  .init = df
)

MgrID       Empl City  Name      Desk Site Location
1  111A   ATL\\Sam  ATL   Sam ATL\\D123  ATL     D123
2  111B ATL\\Sarah  ATL Sarah   HOM\\H1  HOM       H1
3  111C MNL\\Ethel  MNL Ethel MNL\\M456  MNL     M456
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `strsplit` basically.

```
lapply(df[-1], \(x) do.call('rbind', strsplit(x, split='\\\\'))) |>
  do.call(what='cbind.data.frame') |> setNames(c("City", "Name", "Site", "Location")) |> cbind(df)
#   City  Name Site Location MgrID       Empl      Desk
# 1  ATL   Sam  ATL     D123  111A   ATL\\Sam ATL\\D123
# 2  ATL Sarah  HOM       H1  111B ATL\\Sarah   HOM\\H1
# 3  MNL Ethel  MNL     M456  111C MNL\\Ethel MNL\\M456
```